# Is it possible to Read/Search Many Office Documents as XML or a FileStream, to improve speed?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, xml, powershell

I'm curious if it's possible to search for regex matches in Office documents (.doc,.docx,.xls,.xlsx) using FileStreams or opening as XML? My goal is to search a very large number of documents and produce a csv report with the exact matches and the filepath of the file each was found in.

I've read about NPOI in C#, but am unable to get it functioning properly in a powershell script. I have also accomplished my goal by converting all xls and xlsx documents to text files and then searching via a filestream and then using following for Word docs:

```
$objWord = New-Object -Com Word.Application
$objWord.Visible = $false
$objWord.DisplayAlerts = "wdAlertsNone"
$objDocument = $objWord.Documents.Open("$fileSearched")
$paras = $objDocument.Paragraphs
foreach ($para in $paras) { #for each paragraph in paragraphs
      $Search = $para.range.text | Select-String -pattern $RX | Select-Object Path, Matches
            foreach ($item in $Search){
                $Props = @{ #create a properties dictionary
                    Path = $fileSearched #set the item Path to the value of the $Path variable
                    Matches = $item.Matches.Value
                }
            $OBJ = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $Props
            $OBJ | Select-Object Matches,Path | Export-Csv -Path $CSV -Append -NoTypeInformation
            }
}
$objWord.Quit()
```

However this seems quite time consuming, is there a faster way?

Comment: I'd strongly advice against reinventing a indexing engine using Xml and handcrafted regex. There are plenty open source Indexing engines that can do this task for and give you the desired export. If you're on the MS stack even the builtin [Windows Search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965362(v=vs.85).aspx) could do that for you.

Comment: This is a great suggestion, thank you, and we may end up doing this. However, in the meantime, I'm still curious if there's a better way to accomplish my goal.